# Is there any filter option is available to see all duplicate questions in a SE site?

Tags: support, search, duplicate-questions

I want to see all the duplicate questions which were asked by other users in `webmasters.stackexchange.com`. I tried a lot but I don't find any filter option to see only duplicate questions. How can I find those questions alone?